# maintaining state with jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing a `jQuery` plugin that needs to maintain state. There will be multiple instances on a page but each one will have different data associated with keys in a database. I am trying to use the example on the jQuery site as my starting point but have run into some difficulties. Here 'hid' and 'hnid' are the key values I am interested in. In production I will pass them in through options. But my question here is when I click the save button and run the 'save' method, how do I get at my data keys, hid and hnid? Now when I run the code I get a null for data.

```
(function($) {

    var settings = {        
        'background-color': 'blue'
    };

    var saveData = function() {
        var data = $(this).data('inknote');// now this refers to save button so has no 'data' associated with it.
        console.log('data', data);
    }

var methods = {

    init: function(options) {

        return this.each(function() {

            if (options) {
                $.extend(settings, options);
            }
            var $this = $(this),
            data = $this.data('inknote');

            // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
            if (!data) {

                var startData = {
                    target: $this,
                    hid: 1,
                    hnid: 2
                };
                $this.data('inknote', startData);
            }

            var $messageDiv = $('<div>').addClass('messages').html('&nbsp;');
/* am I calling the save method properly here ?*/
                var $saveButton = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').attr('value', 'Save').bind('click', function() { methods['save'].apply(this); });
                var $printButton = $('<input>').attr('type', 'button').attr('value', 'Print').bind('click', function() { methods['print'].apply(this); });
                var $lockStatus = $('<div>').addClass('lock').addClass('unlocked').html('&nbsp;');
                $this.append($messageDiv).append($saveButton).append($printButton).append($lockStatus);
            });
        },
        save: function(el) {

            return $(this).each(function() {
                saveData(this);                
            });
        },
        print: function(el) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    $.fn.inknote = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.inknote');
        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve exactly, but does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/uuRFc/) help?

Comment: Thanks for supplying your answer. It got me going in the right direction. Your code made it clearer that the data item had to be attached to a specific dom element. Also the way the click event passed in the original element that had the plugin attached to it. I just moved the data "encapsulation" to inside the plugin and passed in the keys via the settings. http://jsfiddle.net/voam/uJnQj/

Comment: -1: I know, I know good old SO days, but anyways: [Link-only answers are no good answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) (anything but that the ifaour does confess he did not fully understand the question)